# How to configure the rendering server with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs

I want to create a universal ReactJS app. There was a following problem. When you click on the link page is full refresh.

**server.js**

```
import path from "path";
import express from "express";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
const Router = require("react-router");
const RouterContext = require("react-router").RouterContext;
const routes = require("./Scripts/Configs/RouteConfig");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../", "public")));

app.set("views", path.join("src", "Views"));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  Router.match({ routes: routes.default, location: req.url }, (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err.message);
    } else if (redirectLocation) {
      res.status(302).redirect(redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
    } else if (renderProps) {
      res.status(200).render("index.ejs", {
        reactOutput: ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps} />)
      });
    } else {
      res.status(404).send("Page Not Found");
    }
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("App listening on port 3000!");
});
```

**RouteConfig.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, IndexRoute } from "react-router";

import Layout from "../Components/Theme/Layout";

import Home from "../Components/Home";
import About from "../Components/About";
import Help from "../Components/Help";

export default (
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/help" component={Help} />
        <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    </Route>
);
```

**Layout.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Nav from "./Nav";

class Layout extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { children: routeComponent } = this.props;

        return (
                <div >
                    <Nav />
                    {routeComponent}
                </div >
        );
    }
}

Layout.propTypes = {
    children: React.PropTypes.element
};

export default Layout;
```

**Nav.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router";
class Nav extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/help">Help</Link></li>
                </ul>
        );
    }
}
export default Nav;
```

Every reload, the server sends to the browser is:

**index.html**

```
<div id="root">
    <div data-reactroot="" data-reactid="1" data-react-checksum="904225187">
        <ul data-reactid="2">
            <li data-reactid="3">
                <a href="/" data-reactid="4">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li data-reactid="5">
                <a href="/about" data-reactid="6">About</a>
            </li>
            <li data-reactid="7">
                <a href="/help" data-reactid="8">Help</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div data-reactid="9">home</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why every time the page is reloaded completely? How to fix it?

Comment: It seems your page doesn't contain scripts. Could you plz post `index.ejs` as well?

Comment: Yes, thank you. The error was in the 12th row in the file server.js. app.use(express.static("public"));